# Confused between promise and async/awaits

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

I'm a novice in Node JS. I practice promise and I successfully used it. What I understand is with using a promise you can hold the output and send resolve and reject. I used in database operation.

Then someone suggested me to use async/awaits. So here is my code which ran successfully the first time.

shop.js file

```
const models = require("../models");
const shopModel = models.Shop;
exports.checkShop = function(shopName) {
  return new Promise((reslove, reject) => {
    shopModel
      .findOne({ where: { shop: shopName } })
      .then(rs => {
        if (rs) {
          reslove(rs);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err.toString());
      });
  });
};
```

And the file where i called this

```
const shopController = require("./shop");
exports.getInstall = function(req, res) {

  const shop = req.body.shop;

  if (!cn(shop)) {
    shopController
      .checkShop(shop)
      .then(
        shopCheck =>
          function() {
            if (shopCheck) {
                res.send(`Welcome back ${shopCheck.shop}`);
            } else {
           //my else stuff
            }
          }
      )
      .catch(
        e =>
          function() {
            res.state(500).send(e);
          }
      );
  } else {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(
        "Missing shop parameter. Please add ?shop=your-development-shop.myshopify.com to your request"
      );
  }
};
```

And this is how I tried to replace it with async/awaits. But it does not work.

```
exports.checkShop = async function(shopName) {
    try{
      var rs = await shopModel.findOne({ where: { shop: shopName } });
      if(rs){
        return rs;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      return Promise.reject(new Error(400));
    }
};
```

And the other file

```
exports.getInstall = function(req, res) {
    const shop = req.body.shop;

    if (!cn(shop)) {
      var shopCheck =  shopController.checkShop(shop);
      try {
        if (shopCheck) {
          res.send(`Welcome back ${shopCheck.shop}`);
        } else {
//         else stuff
        }
      } catch (e) {
        res.state(500).send(e);
      }
    } else {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .send(
          "Missing shop parameter. Please add ?shop=your-development-shop.myshopify.com to your request"
        );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Promise version of is fine. I'm struggling with async/await version

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! In fact your first snippet does not work because you forgot the `else` path on the `if (rs)` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function with the `async` keyword before it will (explicitly or implicitly) return a promise.

So when you call `shopController.checkShop` you will either have to do something like

```
shopController.checkShop().then(.... )
```

or make `getInstall` an async function as well so that you can use `await` inside it.

```
exports.getInstall = async function(req, res) {
   // other code here.. 
   const result = await shopController.checkShop(shop);
   //.. 
}
```

**Edit**:

If you want to make `getInstall` async and use `await` on `checkShop` you will have to catch the potential rejection using `try {} catch` like you did in `checkShop`.

Comment: That's perfect. But how do i return reject state in async/await? In promise i can simply do reject(error) and then write a catch after then.

Comment: If you want to make `getInstall` async and use `await` on `checkShop()` you will have to catch the potential rejection using `try {} catch` like you did in `checkShop`.

Comment: @PicksPrabhakar You can either `return Promise.reject(…)` like you did, or you can simply `throw …` an exception.

Comment: Glad I could help!